# Rails 5 - hidden_field_tag populated by JS not submiting form via :onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, onchange, hidden-field

On Rails 5 I'm populating a hidden_field_tag with a date using datepicker jQuery UI function. The view currently looks like this -

```
 <script>
    $( function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline : true,
        altField : "#date_search",
        onSelect : function(){ $('#date_search').submit();} 
        });
    });
    </script>
(...)
<%= form_tag(escala_index_path, :method => :get ) do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag("date_search") %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Which is working fine. But I want to drop the submit_tag and make the form submit the date when it changes, since in a similar form with select_tag the :onchange option worked I tried:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("date_search", "", :onchange => ("this.form.submit();")) %>
```

But nothing happens. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `onSelect : function(){ $('#date_search').submit();} ` should be something like `onSelect : function(){ $('#your-form-id').submit();} `, replace `your-form-id` with the id of your form. e.g: `<%= form_tag(escala_index_path, :method => :get, :id => 'my-form' ) do %>` and `onSelect : function(){ $('#my-form').submit();}`

Comment: At first glance it worked perfectly, tomorrow I will fool around to make sure, thanks a lot for the quick answer! Just a question though, if in the "onSelect" I need to specify the form name, not the param, why it worked with submit_tag?

Answer (score 1):

`$('#date_search').submit();` does not work since the submit event does not bubble up to the form.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    inline : true,
    altField : "#date_search",
    onSelect : function(){ this.form.submit() } 
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing the inline `:onchange => ("this.form.submit();"))` does not work since the jQuery UI Datepicker does not trigger a normal change event on the input.

Comment: This made the page reload when selecting the date, but the param wasn't sent to the server. The inline :onchange worked after I gave the form an id as user fanta commented above. I will have to try to make the date sent as a param selected though (when the page is reloaded/params sent the datepicker goes back to today's date). Thanks anyway.